# Pyright/mypy: "expr" has no attribute "id"

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, type-annotation, pyright

Code:

```
def extract_assignment(assignment: ast.Assign) -> Dict[str, LINES_RANGE]:
    targets = ', '.join(t.id for t in assignment.targets)
```

pyright/mypy:

> error: "expr" has no attribute "id"

From [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/_ast.pyi):

```
class Assign(stmt):
    targets: typing.List[expr]
    value: expr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following Code:

```
x = [100]
x[0] = 200
```

Running the following ast inspection:

```
import ast

code = """
x = [100]
x[0] = 200
"""

root = ast.parse(code)
for node in ast.walk(root):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
        print(type(node.targets[0]))
```

prints the following:

```
<class '_ast.Name'>
<class '_ast.Subscript'>
```

So in this case `ast.expr` can be either `ast.Name` or `_ast.Subscript`.  Only `ast.Name` has an `id` attribute.

To use only `ast.Name`s use the following code:

```
targets = ', '.join(t.id for t in assignment.targets if isinstance(t, ast.Name))
```